# Splunk untable with multiple x-field fields

Tags: splunk, unpivot

I have data that looks like this:

| _time | id | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-22 | abcde | 0 | 45 | 23 |
| 2023-02-23 | abcde | 1 | 4 | 17 |
| 2023-02-22 | xyz | 1 | 46 | 24 |
| 2023-02-23 | xyz | 2 | 5 | 18 |

I want to transform it so that it looks like this:

| _time | id | value_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-22 | abcde | value1 | 0 |
| 2023-02-22 | abcde | value2 | 45 |
| 2023-02-22 | abcde | value3 | 23 |
| 2023-02-23 | abcde | value1 | 1 |
| 2023-02-23 | abcde | value2 | 4 |
| 2023-02-23 | abcde | value3 | 17 |
| 2023-02-22 | xyz | value1 | 1 |

...and so on.

I tried to use untable:

```
| makeresults 
| eval _time="2023-02-22", id="abcde", value1=0, value2=45, value3=23 
| append [| makeresults 
| eval _time="2023-02-23", id="abcde", value1=1, value2=4, value3=17]
| append [| makeresults 
| eval _time="2023-02-22", id="xyz", value1=1, value2=46, value3=24]
| append [| makeresults 
| eval _time="2023-02-23", id="xyz", value1=2, value2=5, value3=18]
| table _time id value1 value2 value3
| untable _time value_name value
```

However, this gives me value_names of "id" on separate rows. I would like to be able to specify more than one field for the x-field parameter of the [untable command](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Untable) so that I get one row for every combination of _time and id.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Additional Solution:

I can't find a way to do this without a *temporary field* but if you want to avoid using rex and let Splunk deal with the fields natively then you could use a multivalue field instead:

```
| eval id_time = mvappend(_time, id)
| fields - id, _time
| untable id_time, value_name, value
| eval _time = mvindex(id_time, 0), id = mvindex(id_time, 1)
| table id, _time, value_name, value
```

If any of your non-transposable fields (e.g. `id` or `_time`) contain null data then you will need to prepend `| fillnull value="******" id` to this solution in order to pad out the mvfield. You can always remove the replacement null values after with  `| eval if(id="******", null(), id)`

### Original Solution:

I have came across this issue before. The best solution I have found is to create a *temporary field* with a delimiter between each of the fields that you don't want to be transposed. Once you are happy with the structure you can then extract them using a `| rex` command.

```
| eval id_time = _time + "|" + id
| fields id_time, value1, value2, value3
| untable id_time, value_name, value
| rex field=id_time "(?<_time>[^\|]+)\|(?<id>.+)"
| table _time, id, value_name, value
```

Since you're using _time which is stored as an integer, I have chosen to use a simple pipe as a delimiter.

Comment: This approach had occurred to me. I was thinking that there must be a better way, but perhaps this is optimal for Splunk, as really it is a text processor. Thanks for the working query. I'll allow a little more time before marking the accepted answer, just in case.

Comment: @RobFisher, I agree this does feel a little bit _hacky_. I do wish that Splunk could handle this sort of use case better, but at least it does provide the flexibility to work around it. I have added an additional idea for you to try, using multivalue fields instead. Cheers!

Comment: that is much better. It is less "hacky" because we don't have to cast everything into a string representation and pull it apart later. Thanks for taking the time to do this.